# TouchEffect not work in ios with a stacklayout?

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent
        };
        var touchEffect = new TouchTracking.Forms.TouchEffect() { Capture = true };
        touchEffect.TouchAction += TouchEffect_TouchAction;
        stackLayout.Effects.Add(touchEffect);
Content=stackLayout;
```

When I touch the simulator it not work. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an existing issue of the plugin . Add the following line to **AppDelegate.cs** in iOS project

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
  global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
  LoadApplication(new App());

  var _ = new TouchTracking.Forms.iOS.TouchEffect();

  return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

Comment: 嗨，这个可以了。还有个问题就是Skiasharp在真机中不管用，在模拟器中正常，这个是为什么？

Comment: Here is a similar issue https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/1026#issuecomment-558792074 which maybe can help you .

Comment: You would better describe your issue in English so that more people can understand it and help you .